# Android widgets horizontal alignment

Tags: android, android-widget

Sorry if I am repeating the question.

I am learning android and working on simple UI of an android project.

On this UI I am having 2 edit texts(select date and rid) and 1 spinner.

As following image shows, these 3 'form widgets' are not aligned properly(Horizontally).

I want to align these widgets with equal distance between them.(Horizontally).

I tried a lot to align them using Linear and Realtive layouts but, am not able to align them properly.

Please suggest me changes in my xml file.

**Here is my xml file** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_day_wise_log"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Day Wise Log"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_day_wise_log" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_daywiselog_selDate"
        android:layout_width="175px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Select Date"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" >
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_daywiselog_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/et_daywiselog_selDate"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_daywiselog_selDate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_daywiselog_rid"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sp_daywiselog_options"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Rid"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_daywiselog_find"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
    android:text="Find" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_daywiselog_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_daywiselog_find" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_daywiselog_selDate"
    android:layout_width="175px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30px"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Select Date"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" 
    android:gravity="right">
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_daywiselog_options"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/et_daywiselog_selDate"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_daywiselog_selDate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:gravity="center">
</Spinner>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_daywiselog_rid"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sp_daywiselog_options"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Rid"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" 
    android:gravity="left">
```

with gravity

Comment: thanks ,tried this but 'select-date and spinner' are little bit overlapping ..any better solution ?

Comment: you can try to add android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ID" and android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ID"